# How do I extract an integer from a file between two characters?

Tags: c++

I want to extract an specific number from a file which contains lines that look like this (the line goes on, this is the only important part):

```
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?wizard=1";
```

Where I have to ignore until I find the character '=' with a `f.ignore(MAX_LONG_LINE, '\n')`. But when it comes to getting the number 1 (it could be any number) in the url, I don't know what to do.

I've tried with `getline(f, num, '"')` but that doesn't support integers and converting from string to int is too advanced for what I'm learning and what my course is. There has to be a simpler method. After that, I tried with `f >> num` but that skips until the next space instead of the '"'.

*num* should result in the number between '=' and '"' in a file, which in the example is 1 but it could be different.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to extract a number after '=' symbol?

Comment: May be using a [regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) is the easiest way.

Comment: Exactly. That's why I used the f.ignore(). And regex would be good too but as I said, this is a basic course and I don't think it's what I should be doing

Comment: @b0ss192301 It's not as basic as you think it is, and will leave you inspecting every character with formatted text extraction, thus using regex is just fine for that case.

Comment: https://ideone.com/nBBr7s how about using stringstream?

Comment: Then I don't know what I'm doing wrong... I'll try with a conversion from string to int which seems easier. Thanks

Comment: @b0ss192301 Better post a [mcve] as required here, then we maybe can help you to find out what's wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this myself:

Turns out  `f >> num` does work, I just needed to add one more ignore before doing it, as it was getting the previous number. If you're having issues with this I suggest you to check you're correctly positioned with `f.ignore(MAX_LONG_LINE, '\n')` or similar methods before anything else. As long as `num` is an integer, it will extract a value of the same type.

Thanks a lot to everyone who helped me.

Answer (score 1):

can be :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  if (argc != 2) {
    cout << "usage : " << argv[0] << " <file path>" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  ifstream in(argv[1]);

  if (!in) {
    cout << "cannot open "  << argv[1] << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  string line;

  in >> line;

  size_t p = line.rfind('=');

  if (p == string::npos) {
    cout << "invalid line '"  << line << "',  = is missing" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  stringstream ss(line.substr(p + 1));
  int n;
  string s;

  ss >> n >> s;

  if (s != "\";") {
    cout << "invalid line '"  << line << "',  must be ...<number>\";'" << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  cout << "number is " << n << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain, in detail, how your answer resolves the OP's issue.  The preferred method on StackOverflow is not to present completed programs, but enough of an example to make the OP think a bit more.